# Does the size of a person matter when Devil Fruit powers are involved?

Tags: one-piece

As seen in the anime, Lily Enstomach grew herself into the size of a giant inside Luffy thus giving Luffy immense power.  He was strong with a weakness of becoming slower.  However, when he went into 2nd gear, the sheer power of turning into 2nd gear caused everything around him to be thrown back.

So does the size determine the amount of initial power the person has?

-The reason why I said initial was because power really matters on the training rather than the power of the devil fruit

**Example:**

Luffy, when he got bigger, the effect of 2nd Gear was stronger.
Let's say that Buggy's devil fruit (section-section) gives Buggy the ability to split and fly a range 25 meters around his feet.  If Buggy was the size of a giant or the size of Whitebeard, would the range increase?

This is not about how much the devil fruit is eaten.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I cannot understand what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: if I'm not wrong those episodes were just fillers, so I wouldn't bother deciphering things which could not be explained there.

Comment: Are you asking about the size of the person? Or about the size of the fruit he eats?

Comment: @madarauchiha i'm asking about the size of the person.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not about devil fruits, it's just that bigger things have bigger impact.

Let's say that a normal giant, without any devil fruit powers, can crush a warship into pieces. However a normal sized person would need some powers (haki, devil fruit, whatever else) no matter how strong he is otherwise, only because his body is smaller and his fist wouldn't make such an impact. He could break through the ship but the damage would remain local. A small hole on the ship, and that's it.

In the special case of devil fruit's powers the only information we have (while seeing numerous occasions of bigger attacks being more powerful, like Luffy's Gear 3rd and Ace's Supernova) what Crocodile said in the desert while fighting Luffy: a devil fruit power can be stronger based on how the user trains and uses it. That implies that indeed, size matters for devil fruit powers too, if the user trains himself and uses it that way. Not because of any devil fruit specific reasons, just because of the facts mentioned above.

Comment: This is why Luffy tends to use Gear Third whenever something big needs wrecking.